# How to get TokenIds of Nft the user have in solidity?

Tags: solidity

We can fetch the TokenIds using Web3 call and check the transfer events but is it possible to fetch the ids in solidity?

Comment: Do you mean to fetch all the token ids? Or the token id by address?

Comment: Hi @pedropedro I mean using my wallet address how can i fetch all token Ids which i have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually to check for the presence of a specific NFT in a wallet, the IERC721 interface is used:

```
interface IERC721 is IERC165 {

  ...

  /**
  * @dev Returns the number of tokens in ``owner``'s account.
  */
  function balanceOf(address owner) external view returns (uint256 balance);

  ...

}
```

as this allows for the following code in solidity:

```
function walletHoldsToken(address memory _wallet, address memory _contract) public view returns (bool) {
  return IERC721(_contract).balanceOf(_wallet) > 0
}
```

The functionality you are requesting which is

> to fetch the ids in solidity

does not have support in the existing IERC721 interface. So the easiest thing to do, would be to create your own interface that provides the functionality you need, and implement it in your contract by specifying the interface and providing the supporting method. So for instance:

```
interface IERC721TokenIdDiscovery is IERC721 {
  function getTokenIdsByOwner(address _wallet) public view returns (uint256[] tokenIds);
}
```

You would then be able to use this function in your other solidity code:

```
uint256[] tokenIds = IERC721TokenIdDiscovery(_contract).getTokenIdsByOwner(_wallet);
```